# Always getting empty object on ajax request in october CMS

Tags: ajax, octobercms

Here is my js code:

```
$('body').on('change','#cash-amount-id',function(){
     var amount = $(this).val();
     calculateCODcharge(amount);
 });

function calculateCODcharge(amount){
    $('.loading-img').show();
    if(amount>0 ){
       $.request('onCalculateCODcost', {
            data: {amount: amount},
            success: function(response, status, xhr, $form) {
              console.log(response);
              $('#cod_cost_text').text(response.result);
              calculateTotalCharge();
              $('.loading-img').hide();
          },
          error: function(error){
            console.log(error);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

And my onCalculateCODcost function is:

```
function onCalculateCODcost(){
    $data = post();
    extract($data);

    $cod = \Spot\Shipment\Models\OtherSetting::where('param', 'cod')->get();

    $cod_charge = 0;
    if($cod[0]->enabled){
       $cod_charge = $amount*$cod[0]->value;
       $cod_charge /=100;
    }
    //echo $cod_charge;
    return 100;//$cod_charge;
}
```

To be sure about this weird problem I just return 100; But I can see empty response in console. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change  `return $cod_charge;` to  `return array('cod'=>$cod_charge);`. Meaning return type should be array. Hope this will help others for such situation.

Answer (score 0):

I change `return $cod_charge;` to `return array('cod'=>$cod_charge);`. Meaning return type should be array. Hope this will help others for such situation.